# Pure(Vanilla) Javascipt set transition and style synchronously,and it does not performance as I want

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, css-transitions

As I my code below

1. I click btn-01, bg-01 opactity from 0 to 1, and left from 0 to 300px (1200ms)
2. And then I click btn-02, bg-01 need to from opacity 0.3 to 1, and left from 150px to 450px (1200ms)

```js
let bg = document.querySelector(".bg-01")

document.querySelector(".btn-01").addEventListener("click",function(){
  bg.style.transitionDuration = "1200ms"
  bg.style.left = "300px"
  bg.style.opacity = "1"
})
document.querySelector(".btn-02").addEventListener("click",function(){
  bg.style.transitionDuration = "0ms"
  bg.style.left = "150px"
  bg.style.opacity = "0.3"
  // setTimeout(()=>{
    bg.style.transitionDuration = "1200ms"
    bg.style.left = "450px"
    bg.style.opacity = "1"
  // },10)
  
})
```

```css
.bg-01 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type"button" class="btn-01">001</button>
<button type"button" class="btn-02">002</button>

<div class="bg-01" style="opacity:0; left:0;">
  
</div>
```

but It doesn't performance as I want.

In step 2, when click btn-02 ,bg-01 just move: left from 300px to 450px.

In my logic: Because of duration set "0ms",bg-01 suddenly go to the place left:150px (so as opacity)
and then duration set "1200ms",and then bg-01 go to the place left:450px

But it just move from 300px to 450px directly...

Why this happend???

I just solve this by add setTimeout.

Does it has any way to solve this problem?